# NumPy - Find most common value in array, use largest value in case of a tie

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

There are so many questions around that deal with finding the most common value in an array, but all of them return the "first" element in case of a tie. I need the highest value from the list of tied elements, imagine something like this:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = [1, 1, 3, 3]
most_common = np.bincount(my_array).argmax()
```

This gives me `1`, which is obviously not wrong, but I have a tied result here and I want to decide on my own what I want to do in that case. For my application, in case of such a tie I want the highest value from `my_array`, which is `3`. How can I do that?

*PS: need a Python 2.7 answer... sorry, but can't change that at the moment*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply `argmax` to the reversed output of `bincount`, and then adjust to take into account the reversal:

```
In [73]: x
Out[73]: array([3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4])

In [74]: b = np.bincount(x)

In [75]: b
Out[75]: array([2, 5, 3, 5, 1])

In [76]: most_common = len(b) - 1 - b[::-1].argmax()

In [77]: most_common
Out[77]: 3
```

Comment: This one works also for arrays without ties and still gives the correct result in any case. So I'll go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you'd go about solving this with Numpy, as there is no way to alter the tie-breaking logic of `argmax`, but you can do it with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) easily:

```
from collections import Counter

my_array = [1, 1, 3, 3]
counter = Counter(my_array)
most_common, num_occurances = max(counter.most_common(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

Comment: After the initial euphoria, I just found that this only works in such a very specific case and does not really give me a correct result in case of non-ties. For example, if `my_array = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4]`, the result is `4`, which is absolutely wrong.